# Neo4j query: conditional match

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have this model:

[image]

- Bob and Alice are Users
- CVI is a clinic
- Pluto is an animal

The users have a property called *identityId* (CONSTRAINT UNIQUE) to identify the user.

I would like to select the User with a given id only if it is the user itself (same identityId) or if it exists a relationship SHARED_WITH between the Alice and Bob.

In terms of performance, is the query below the best query for that?

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE id(u) = {id} AND ((u.identityId = {identityId}) 
                OR ((:User { identityId: {identityId} }) - [:OWNS] -> (:Clinic) <- [:SHARED_WITH] - (u))) 
RETURN u
```

**Example**

- Alice { id: 6, identityId: "5678"}
- Bob { id: 3, identityId: "1234"}
- Mallory { id: 5, identityId: "2222"}

*First case: The caller is Alice*

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE id(u) = 6 AND ((u.identityId = "5678") 
                OR ((:User { identityId: "5678" }) - [:OWNS] -> (:Clinic) <- [:SHARED_WITH] - (u))) 
RETURN u
```

The u is Alice

*Second case: The caller is Bob*

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE id(u) = 6 AND ((u.identityId = "1234") 
                OR ((:User { identityId: "1234" }) - [:OWNS] -> (:Clinic) <- [:SHARED_WITH] - (u))) 
RETURN u
```

The u is Alice

*Third case: The caller is Mallory*

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE id(u) = 6 AND ((u.identityId = "2222") 
                OR ((:User { identityId: "2222" }) - [:OWNS] -> (:Clinic) <- [:SHARED_WITH] - (u))) 
RETURN u
```

The u is NULL (mallory is neither the user nor the user with Alice has shared its user)

Comment: The property `identityId` is unique?

Comment: Yes it is a CONSTRAINT UNIQUE

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. Give an example of input data. And the desired result.

Comment: I hope now it is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your additional explanations:

```
// Get user by id
MATCH (I:User) WHERE id(I) = {id}
  // Whom with given {identityId} shard with him
  OPTIONAL MATCH (U:User {identityId: {identityId} })
                 -[:OWNS]->()<-[:SHARED_WITH]-
                 (I)
  WITH I, COUNT(U) as UC
    // Test user {identityId} 
    // or there are those who with {identityId} are with him shares
    WHERE I.identityId = {identityId} OR UC > 0
RETURN I
```

Comment: I know only the identityId of the caller that can be different from the user id that I'm looking for. It works like a permission. I want read the data from User with the given id only if I have the rights (either I'm the user with the identityId or the user with the given Id has a shared relationship with me)

Comment: I must use id to select the user and then I have to know if the user that make the call (identityId) have the rights to accomplish the operation. See my query

Comment: @aGO See update. I hope I have understood you correctly this time :)

Comment: ok now it is better ;-). But do you think it is better of mine in terms of performance?

Comment: Your query has 1 db hits less, you won :-D